# Need to initialize a currency field to blank or null in a process

Tags: fields, currency

Before calculating currency field values, I need to initialize all of these fields to be blank or null values as different fields may need to be populated based on updates to opportunity start and end dates. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the field to a global constant called $GlobalConstant.Null